# Blender 4 Donut Tutorial (Part 9): Black Spots on Icing

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, subsurface-scattering

I've just finished part 9 of the Blender 4 donut tutorial, and when I render everything in Cycles, this weird thing happens. Does this have something to do with Subsurface Scattering? Even after turning Subsurface > Random walk down to 0 for both the icing and the sprinkles, I still get some weird black lines on the icing. I'm not sure I get what the issue is here exactly.

Here's a screenshot of the original problem:
[image]

And here's a screenshot after I had set Random walk to 0 for both the icing and sprinkles.
[image: My Error]

If any more information such as new images is needed, please let me know. Thank you in advance.